# Encryption of password for a Single Sign On

Tags: c#, single-sign-on

in the next few weeks I am planning to implement a SSO to make the life of my colleagues easier.
A user logs on our server and as soon as he is logged in, the whole process starts. Applications are started and the needed passwords should be automatically inserted. So far so good. The passwords will be stored in a database and that's exactly where I need some help. 
Simple hashing won't help since I need the clear passwords for the whole process, am I right? So I need some kind of encrypted passwords in the database which I will decrypt at runtime. I'm not using C# for a very long time and the only thing I found was the System.Security.Cryptography-Namespace. Are there better methods? Any advice is welcomed.

Thanks in advance

// ALL applications/websites which need to be started are third party applications with different credentials for each one of them.

Comment: Firstly why do you NEED to have a password in the clear? Secondly why aren't you using an off the shelf SSO implementation, such as Kerberos or ADFS? Thirdly, if you are writing your own security protocol, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Please tell us what your main account log in is at work. If you use windows I would advise either NTLM/Kerberos or ADFS.

Comment: @Aron As I said I just started to think about the implementation, so I am thankful for any kind of input. The users do use Windows.

Comment: Just use the wealth of information of how to implement Windows auth on your server side. Its pretty much built in to every server-client IPC mechanism in .net

Comment: @Aron Thank you for your help. Maybe I should really look into those implementations. I just thought that my problem is way too specific to use any of these since I need to start some third party applications as well as a bunch of websites and each one of them needs different credentials. Storing all the different passwords in a database seemed to be the most logical approach for me. Nevertheless I thank you for your input and your time.

Comment: You never said ANYTHING about third party websites. Perhaps you should detail your actual problem.

Comment: @Aron Welp yeah I'm very sorry. I understood your approach very well and I was sitting here for about 20 minutes thinking how in the hell I could use them. User X logs into his account on our windows-server. He needs to start several third party applications on his desktop. For each one of them he needs to enter different credentials. Same goes for websites, he needs to open them and enter different credentials as well.

Comment: Proper SSO with third party should be based on federated security. You should look at SAML and ADFS (assuming your third party providers work with SAML). Its similar to how you log-in to stackoverflow using google or facebook.